# Got error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery

I didn't find any info about this error in `jquery 1.7.2min.js` file.

This is my`jquery.1.7.2.min.js` file: http://pastebin.com/Ba2hw3Av

At first, I can't figure out which place is wrong, any ideas? This jQuery file in 3 lines, don't know why.

Error mesage in developer tool: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

This is my OWN code: http://pastebin.com/UnuiCXEr , in this page I got jquery problem (5 s lag with opera, with mozila i got pop up due to jquery error)

Comment: You probably have an infinite loop or recursion somewhere. This error is probably from your code using the jQuery library, not jQuery itself, but that's difficult to say since you didn't post your own code here, just the jQuery library (which is fairly useless).

Comment: Please post your own code and the error stack.

Comment: Mh, okey but what about my own code? I got this error when ordering product in shop. So somewhere in that step code shoulg be problem when using jquery library?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UnuiCXEr this is my own code - its place where I got error.

Comment: So, any ideas where is the problem? I can`t figure out. I got 3-5 sec lag when opening this page (code link in description). I know that error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in jquery.1.7.2.min.js but as u said i should look my code which cause it..